Transparent BSDF makes object and shadow invisible, but not through Mix Shader
this is my first post here, I'm new to Blender and I'm having an issue trying to achieve a certain effect.
I'm trying to make an object become invisible when you look at it from certain angles. I'm using a Vector Transform node from World to Camera, and through a Color Ramp and a Mix Shader I can change between a Transparent BSDF and the Principled BSDF as I move the view through the scene. This works great for the object, but it keeps the shadow visible.

I set the Blend Mode and the Shadow Mode to Alpha Clip, and if I connect the Transparent BSDF directly to the Material Output it hides the shadow too. If I tweak the Mix Shader's Fac manually or through a Value node it also works well.

But with any dynamic configuration it gets stuck in the same state (always casts shadows or never casts shadows) regardless of where I look a it from. I tried clamping the color luminance to 0-1, passing it through a Greater Than node (which always should return 0 or 1), but nothing seems to work for the shadow. Could this be a bug? Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?
Thank you.
